# Simple SPI device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, spi

I have written a simple driver for a character device in Non Blocking mode using epoll.
Now I would like to use that driver for SPI interface.

What should be the device name or how will I map the actual device with the kernel ? 
How will I use the interrupt?

Also who is the Master and Slave?Suppose I am connecting a SPI compatible device to the panda board.Will that device becomes a slave and the development board becomes Master?

I am a newbie.I am using a panda board.
In what way should I go through the Technical Reference manual?

I would really appreciate if anybody would explain and clarify my doubts.

Comment: panda board is master and your spi compatible device is slave. Can you please post the code of your driver ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to connect your driver to a SPI bus driver.  This requires a slight reworking of your driver.  See `drivers/spi/spi.c`

You'll be using the commands for the bus (master, the CPU side) to read and write the commands to the unit.

I don't know what a Panda board is, but if it connects via SPI, it might be a master, but it is probably a slave.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the basics of spi [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/spi/spi-summary?a=arm)

Comment: I could not relate that link with the char driver which I have written.Can you relate it? for ex. In char driver we define .open,.close and also module_init but its nowhere found here in that link.

Comment: I think a hint for this is in the /include/linux/spi/spi.h header. The controller driver needs a protocol driver which oes the real file operations. The fle operations are then mapped to the mentioned operations in the contrller driver.